# Detect USB device and show contents

Tags: php, python, ruby, macos, titanium

Basically I'm using Titanium Desktop to develop a program that reads and plays content from a USB device (mass storage), I've managed to use Ruby to detect removable USB devices on windows and get an array containing paths to any '.mov' files on them, the issue comes when trying to do the same thing on MacOS X or at least I haven't tried as there doesn't seem to be anything around.

Basically with Titanium Desktop I can use Python, Ruby or PHP and mix it with HTML and JavaScript. I've got everything else sorted it's just reading from a mass storage device and listing all files with the '.mov' extension.

Does anyone have and ideas for Mac?
My apologies if I'm crossing over too many languages but I didn't want to triple post the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using pyobjc and python, or macruby. the key thing is to add an observer to the NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification, NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification notifications.

e.g. in pyobjc, it's something like this:

```
class yourObserverClass(NSObject):
  def yourHandler_(self, evt):
    do something here

notifCenter = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().notificatonCenter()
notifCenter.addObserver_selector_name_object_(yourObserverClass, 'yourHandler:', NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification, nil)
```